# vectorの二次元配列からメンバ関数を動かしたい

Tags: c++

2次元配列から1次元配列のメンバ関数に触りたいのですが、動作しません。
直接1次元配列から呼べば動いてくれます。
「そういう仕様だから当然だ」と言われればそれまでですが、
参考にした [サイト](https://qiita.com/ysuzuki19/items/df872d91c9c89cc31aee#2%E6%AC%A1%E5%85%83%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97-3) でも同じ記法が載っていたので諦めきれていない状況です。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv {v};
  //動く
  v.push_back(1);
　//動かない     
  vv[0].push_back(2);
  for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
    std::cout << v[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

上記のコードの出力が 1 になってしまいます。
begin()やend()も正しく処理されず例外が発生します。
上記のコードをコンパイル、実行してもエラーは出ませんでした。

1. 何故うまく動かないのか
2. 近いコードを書くのにどのような方法があるか

教えてほしいです。

環境  OS: Windows 10 19044.1826  IDE: Visual Studio Code 1.70.0  コンパイラ: Clang 14.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「2.近いコードを書くのにどのような方法があるか」についてです。
この方針が良いかどうかはさておき、やりたいことはこういうことでしょうか。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>* > vv {&v};
    //動く
    v.push_back(1);
    // 一応動く
    vv[0]->push_back(2);
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

スコープとかも気にしないといけませんし、管理が面倒そうですが、どちらのvectorを操作しても値が入るようになります。

Answer (score 0):

「1. 何故うまく動かないのか」に対する回答だけ。

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv {v};
```

これでは`vv[0]`に`v`をコピーすることになってしまうため、コピーした後にいくら`v`を変更しても`vv[0]`は変更されませんし、`vv[0]`を変更しても`v`は変更されません。